# delete if 30days old by folder name

Tags: date, powershell

I am trying to delete all folders that are passed 30 days old but I need to base it off of the folder name instead of the creation date. Files get generated and put into a folder with the month on it and inside of it the Month date and year. The Month format is like this MM yyyy and month date like MMddyyyy. I had a script working in powershell v2 that worked well but stopped working in powershell V3.

This was my V2 script

```
function Delete-Folder-30days

$today = get-date -displayhint date
$30days = (get-date).AddDays(-30)

$folders = (gci "\\$args\Apps\AndrewTest" | where-object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True})


foreach ($f in $folders) {
$folderdate = get-date -mont $f.Name.substring(0,2) -day $f.Name.substring(2,2) -year $f.Name.substring(4,2)


if ($folderdate)
    {
    Remove-Item "\\$args\Apps\AndrewTest\$f" -recurse
    }
   }
}

Delete-Folder-30days $Server
```

What could i be doing wrong here?

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: How *exactly* did it "stop working"? Do you get an error? Is the value of `$folderdate` correct?

Comment: When I run it in V2 it will delete everything in the Directory, when it is ran in V3 I get an error saying it cant find the path

    Cannot find path '\\PLBUADRHQTTC099\TransXtest\' because it does not exist

Comment: A few things could be wrong. Your missing a bracket, and I would assume a year would be 4 characters and not 2. But theres nothing here that would be different from 2.0 to 3.0. The reason everything is deleted is because you are saying if($folderdate) ... which will be true if $folderdate is not 0, so its always true

Comment: -Mont is enough to uniquely identify -Month, so that should work fine. The year thing is going to cause him issues though unless he is trying to find things within Christ's lifetime (`-Year 14` will produce a date in 0014, not 2014 as I would assume you intend to do).

Comment: Correct, the dates of the folders come in with the format MMddyy and I cannot use the creation date as my source to delete them because sometimes a file for a dateearlier might be created a day after. I tried to change the -year to (4,4) and changed some test name to MMddyyyy and it still deleted everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [DateTime]::ParseExact() method, it's much simpler for your purposes:

```
function Delete-Folder-30days{
    gci "\\$args\Apps\AndrewTest" -Directory | ?{[datetime]::ParseExact($_.Name,"MMddyyyy",$null) -lt (get-date).AddDays(-30)} | Remove-Item -Recurse
}

Delete-Folder-30days $Server
```

**Edit:** Sorry! Had the String and Format switched (should be like `("04122014","MMddyyyy",$null)`) but I had the first two arguments reversed.

**Edit2:** You want it to include .zip files as well? There's a couple of things. If you want to include all files then it is really simple. Just remove the `-Directory` from the `GCI` command and it will look at all files and folders in the target directory. If you ONLY want folders and .ZIP files then it gets a little more complicated. Basically we will still remove the -Directory switch, but we'll have to add some filtering into the Where clause as such:

```
?{($_.PSIsContainer -and [datetime]::ParseExact($_.Name,"MMddyyyy",$null) -lt (get-date).AddDays(-30)) -or ($_.Extension -ieq ".zip" -and [datetime]::ParseExact($_.BaseName,"MMddyyyy",$null) -lt (get-date).AddDays(-30))}
```

So now instead of just checking the specially formatted date, you are asking Is this a folder, or does it have the .zip file extension? If at least one of those two is true, does it match the specially formatted date?

Comment: Ran this and got an error saying "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

Comment: That was my bad, I've updated my answer. I had the first two arguments for ParseExact() switched.

Comment: That works beautifully, and that way I can keep the folders format as MMddyy. Thanks!

Comment: If this answer works for you please mark it as accepted for the benefit of future users with similar questions.

Comment: Will do, quick question though. Is there away to make it delete zip folders with a siimilar name?

Comment: When I take out the -Directory parameter i get this error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

Comment: That'll happen when it tries to process names that are not MMddyy. Hm, actually, I just realized the files .Name includes extension. Give me a minute and I'll update it to fix that.

Comment: Use the code at the end and it should be ok, unless you have .Zip files that are not named MMddyy in the folder.

Comment: Sorry I'm coming back to this so late, I got distracted and never got back around to it. I don't get any errors now and it deletes everything 30 days old except the .zip files. Which are the important ones to be deleted.